# Build Gradle build sucessful but never stop after completion & does not open app

Tags: android

Error Image:

Its never Stop running application & Build App also not complete.. I tried  lot of time.Could you please anyone help me...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's an issue with your running Gradle daemon (the one that's building your project).

If it freezes you can either kill the process via terminal, or you can just reboot Android Studio.

Try rebooting for now. However if it keeps happening, you can run this command here:

```
gradlew --stop
```

**You can read more about the commands here:**
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#gradle_daemon_options